# Add New HTML Row & Insert Into Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following js file:

```
function displayResult() {
    var table=document.getElementById("addTable");
    var row=table.insertRow(2);
    var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML="<input type='text' name='expense[]' style='padding:2px;' size='80'>";
    cell2.innerHTML="<div align='center'><input type='text' name='expensecost[]'         style='padding:2px;' size='6'></div>";
}
```

This allows me to add a new row on to my table.  It adds it below:

```
<tr>
    <td align='left' width='350'>
        <input type='text' name='expense[]' style='padding:2px;' size='80'>
    </td>
    <td align='center' width='100'>
        <input type='text' name='expensecost[]' style='padding:2px;' size='6'>
    </td>
</tr>
```

On the click of this button:

```
<button type='button' onclick='displayResult()'>Add Expense</button>
```

This all works fine.  However, when I add new rows and insert them into the database using:

```
foreach ($_POST['expense'] as $index => $id) {
    $sql="INSERT into b_report_expense2 (TASK_ID,EXPENSE_DESC,EXPENSE_COST,REF)
          VALUES ('$_POST[taskid]','$_POST[expense][$index]',
                  '$_POST[expensecost][$index]','$_POST[refid]')";
}
```

It adds taskid and refid in fine but for the expense and expense cost it says:

```
|  Array[0]  | 0
|  Array[1]  | 0
|  Array[2]  | 0
```

This happens when I try to add 3 rows obviously.  What is the cause of this and how do I fix it?  Do I need another array in there that is unique?  Not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your SQL to something like

```
$sql="INSERT into b_report_expense2 (TASK_ID,EXPENSE_DESC,EXPENSE_COST,REF)
      VALUES (
      '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['taskid']) . "',
      '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['expense'][$index]) . "',
      '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['expensecost'][$index]) . "',
      '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['refid']) . "')";
```

You'd be better off using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) and [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to add element numbers into the HTML output.

```
<input type='text' name='expense[0]' style='padding:2px;' size='80'>
```

And I would also change the $sql variable to:

```
$sql="INSERT into b_report_expense2 (TASK_ID,EXPENSE_DESC,EXPENSE_COST,REF) VALUES('".$_POST['taskid']."','".$_POST['expense'][$index]."','".$_POST['expensecost'][$index]."','".$_POST['refid']."')";
```

Comment: you have an additional <> arround your input and adding the index key isn't necessary. The SQL line however wouldn't work as taskid, expense, expensecode & refid is not a constant

Comment: corrected the html output. but refid is int I guess. expenses and expensecost could be anything which can cause wrong interpretation

Comment: shouldn't the taskid, expense, expensecode & refid be enclosed in single quotation marks?

Comment: that depends on the fields used for the database table

Comment: not the table names i mean the $_POST['taskid'] instead of $_POST[taskid] in the VALUES

Comment: your are absolutely right . its been a while I have worked with php ;-) thank you

Comment: Any idea how I can get it to add all rows instead of the last one?

Comment: Liam Sorsby said its not necessary - So you can try name="expense[]". But I had the experiences that sometimes it fail (depended on browsers I guess). So I used javascript to set a proper index number between the brackets..